# Replace the ajax value in the text box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How to replace the `Ajax` value in text box value?

My code is below:

```
<input type="text" 
  id="category_name" 
  name="category_name" 
  value="<?php
            if(isset($compName)) {
              echo ucfirst($compName);
            } else {
              echo"Category";
            }
         ?>" onfocus="javascript:this.value='';" 
             onblur="javascript: if(this.value==''){this.value='<?php
          if(isset($compName)) {
            echo ucfirst(addslashes($compName));
          } else {
            echo"Category";
          }
        ?>';}" onKeydown="javascript: if (event.keyCode==13)serachProduct();"/>
```

When I am typing another value it cannot accept the ajax value.

I will fill chennai means it will not accept the ajax value.

Comment: Replace AJAX value? What do you mean?

Comment: i think you want to say the response you get from an ajax request. right???

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you're trying to say in your explanation. But I got something from your Question alone.

You want to fill your textbox with a value returned from ajax call. 
I suggest you two ways.

for example, this is your textbox `<input type='text' name='city >`

**first method, (I used to do),**

- cover your textbox with a div and pin a id on it. `<div
  id='tb'>--text box--</div>`
- your server script should be echo `"<input type='text' name='city
  value='".$value."'>";`
- on success method of ajax write `$("#tb").html(result);`
- other way to replace html content is `document.getElementById("tb").innerHTML=result;`

**Second method (json,efficient way),**

- `encode_json(array_of_values);`
- **make it as java object** on return of ajax call.
- simply `$("#tb").val(--java-variable--);`

Next time please post your question exactly what you want to ask.